# Enable chrome plugin programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is problem with Citrix receiver application. App will install plugins for browser, but for some reason Chrome plugin is by default disabled. That problem is already reported for some time.

Citrix has detection if receiver is installed. I have my own detection if receiver is installed and we bout have problem with Citrix receiver on Chrome.

Is it possible to enable plugin in Chrome with js or can I get list of all installed plugins. I know that I can get enabled plugins with

```
navigator.plugins
```

Comment: I don't think Javascript can see disabled plugins. I don't even think they can see enabled plugins except by their effects.

Comment: You can detect plugins with navigator.plugins (crome and FF) and on IE you can detect it with ActivXObject but you must know what are you looking for

Comment: This would be a huge security problem, I can't imagine that this is possible.